# Boost.Asio Asynchronous TCP client and multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, client, boost-asio

My application is a TCP client that closely resembles the [Boost.Asio chat client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp).

I'm adding a few separate threads that call chat_client::write. Does this mean I would have to add a locking mechanism to do_write or handle_write? is there any recommended method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to lock it in that case (in general). The events will only be handled from threads that have an io_service running. If that is only one, no locking is required. post()'ing new messages to an io_service is already thread-safe from multiple calling threads.

In your specific example, you might want to take the chat_message by-value instead of by-reference, or it might go out of scope in the post()'ing thread before being used in the io_service thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you would need some sort of locking because of shared resources or whatever, you should have a look at [strands](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html).